# IONIC Build error

Tags: android, ionic-framework, push-notification

When I am running the **ionic build android** command I am getting the below error.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.

  > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':_debugCompile'.
  >   Could not find any version that matches com.android.support:support-v4:+.
  >    Searched in the following locations:
  >        https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/support-v4/maven-met
  >   adata.xml
  >        https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/support-v4/
  >    Required by:
  >        :android:unspecified
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug
  option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 11.915 secs
Error: Error code 1 for command: cmd with args: /s,/c,"D:\morrison\myApp\platfor
ms\android\gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b D:\morrison\myApp\platforms\android\build.gr
adle -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true -Pandroid.useDeprecatedNdk=true"

I have checked the sdk and the android support seems to be installed. Please let me know how I can resolve this issue

Comment: Did you install Google Repository to SDK ?

Comment: Please let me know how to add the same as the android sdk manager is not showing it

Answer (score 0):

you should open sdk manager and you can see Google Repository under the Extras folder 
[image]